# How do I correctly shift arrays on a Tetris line clear?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structure, grid

I'm writing a Tetris clone in C++ and I am at the last stage, I need to delete a row when it is full. Once a piece falls it is stored in a boolean array `grid[20][10]`. For example I check which row is full (or `true`), if so I call a method `deleteRow`, where `n` is a number of row:

```
void Grid::deleteRow(int n)
{
  for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
   {
     grid[n][j] = false;
   }
}
```

Once the row is deleted I call `moveRowDown`:

```
void Grid::moveRowDown()
{
  for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
   {
    for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
     {
       grid[i+1][j]=grid[i][j];
     }
  }
}
```

This does not work, and all of the pieces disappear. What logic am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i is 0 you copy the row 0 into the row 1, then i is 1 and you copy the row 1 into the row 2, etc. The problem is that when you copy the row 1, it has already been overriden.

You probably also have a problem when i = HEIGHT because i+1 is out of bounds.

The solution would be to iterate from the bottom row to the top row (from HEIGHT-1 to 1):

```
for (i = HEIGHT-1; i > 0; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
  {
    grid[i][j]=grid[i-1][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thank you very much for explaining the logic behind it! I appreciate your time! Thank you again!